# Unable to use rosrun

Tags: ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`

```
$ rosrun turtlesim
Usage: rosrun [--prefix cmd] [--debug] PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.
```

I was also unable to use rosrun for locating executable in another package. Any suggestion on what could be the reason for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343202/unable-to-use-rosrun/) by [shashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50434/shashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Welcome to the community!

Your issue is that you've not included a node to run. The `rosrun` syntax is:

```
rosrun <package name> <executable name>
```

So you've gotten the package name correct with `turtlesim`, but you're missing the actual node itself you're trying to run. For this demo, what you're looking for is:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

Happy ROSing

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-04**:
@stevemacenski: it's actually `rosrun`, not `roslaunch` ;)

**Comment by [shashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50434/shashi/) on 2020-02-06**:
Thanks for your answer.

I see in a video lecture that rosrun work as listing the executables in the package when run without node name. However, even after providing package and executable name, I am getting the error that package is not found.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-06**:
If you have just the rosrun and turtlesim, and you tab complete it should give you the list, but that's not the same thing as running.

I don't know what video lecture you're referring to.

Are you sure you've actually built this package, installed it, or sourced the setup.sh file to get it in your environment paths?